# Excel 2007 show formula result in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have in COL 1 many rows containing simple expressions (addition, substraction, multiplication and division with brackets) and I need to show the result in another cell.

Example of an end result of my sheet would be:

COL 1           ___________   COL 2

5.1*3+2,5   _________       17.8

3*(2.6/2-1) ________       0.9

5+6*2-3/3    _________   16

Thank you in advance, hope I was clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using VBA Macro. I am not too sure if there exists any Function or Expressions that can directly evaluate a Text as an Expression in Excel.

In Excel workbook press ALT + F11 to open VBA

Insert a Macro and type the following code into it

```
Function EvaluateExp(Ref As String)
   Application.Volatile
   EvaluateExp = Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

Save the workbook as any filename.xlsm i.e. Macro enabled Excel Sheet.
This creates a custom formula to evaluate text expression to its result. Now we use this formula in Excel. Note that this will only work in an Excel workbook that contains this Macro. Copying the formula to another sheet shall result into an error because the Macro is missing.

Now your expressions are in say A2 thru A6, so in cells B2  type the following formula and drag it down.

```
=EvaluateExp(CONCATENATE("=",(A2)))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way to do this using the built-in EVALUATE() function.  It's a bit strange because it can only be used as part of a named range.

To do this, select your first result cell (B2 here) and define a name for the cell.  In my version of Excel, you get to this dialog by choosing Insert > Name > Define...  (But judging from pat2015's picture, not his version.)

The key is to use the EVALUATE() function in the "Refers to:" box.

[image]

After the range is defined, you can enter the name in B2 just like a function:

[image]

And filling down calculates all the answers from the text expressions.

[image]

This does essentially the same thing as pat2015's answer, but you don't have to create a macro.  This IS using a macro, so you do need to save your workbook as .xlsm.  You'll get a notice about that when you save it.